# Why my wordpress loopback traffic while socket is setup?

Tags: mysql

my wordpress generate huge loopback traffic even if i setup socket:

```
define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1:/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock');
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4');
define('DB_COLLATE', 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci');
```

Why it's happen?

I used tcpdump and i've seen sql queries and answers. Looks like it ignores the sock file. I;ve checked - its only php-fpm process (7.0.16) what work with mysql on port 3306.

I have only wordpress installed.

here is my mysqld section: [gist](https://gist.github.com/nikitasius/024812e254f96b26ad8d84c35d35374c).

Answer (score 0):

Finally, because i had **chroot**'ed php-fpm and it can't access sock file out of chroot.

I didn't noticed it in my question.